# Can we add different icon in a single symbol layer in mapbox?

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox

So currently I am making two symbol layers and GeoJsonSource for two types of symbol in my code - one set of symbols are active and another set is inactive symbols. I am doing this because I have two sets of symbols, therefore, I have made two GeoJsonSource.

```
val source_Active = GeoJsonSource("GeoJsonSourceActive", FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(listoflnglat_active),GeoJsonOptions().withCluster(true).withClusterMaxZoom(16).withClusterRadius(40))
    val source_Passive = GeoJsonSource("GeoJsonSourcePassive", FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(listoflnglat_passive),GeoJsonOptions().withCluster(true).withClusterMaxZoom(16).withClusterRadius(40))
    style.addSource(source_Active)
    style.addSource(source_Passive)
    val symbolLayerActive = SymbolLayer("Active","GeoJsonSourceActive")
    val symbolLayerPassive = SymbolLayer("Passive","GeoJsonSourcePassive")
    symbolLayerActive.withProperties(PropertyFactory.iconImage("marker-icon-active"))
    symbolLayerPassive.withProperties(PropertyFactory.iconImage("marker-icon-passive"))
    style.addLayer(symbolLayerActive)
    style.addLayer(symbolLayerPassive)
```

Can I do it in a single layer because I want to perform clustering and I want that all icons cluster into one single icon after a certain level of zoom out

Comment: Have you seen this example: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbol-layer-clustering/? It uses a single layer with multiple icons for its clustering.

Comment: But it is using two different symbol layer one for clustered and another unclustered. I have two icons in unclustered itself!!!